# How to take control of a connection in an apache c module

Tags: c, module, apache2, apache-modules

I am writing an apache module. I need to recieve arbitrary data from the client after authentication. In principle my solution requires me to write a loop that allows the program to read and write from a socket — *or the apache underlying mechanism for socket IO*.

I know this might be the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), but I can't think of another way to do this. My program is ready to start bidirectional communication but I have searched the web and I have failed to find something useful.

I also inspected the `request_rec` structure and all the relevant structures of some of it's fields and I didn't find anything that looks interesting or relevant for this problem.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding you correctly... you're writing an HTTP server extension, but you want to deviate from the normal HTTP request/response pattern of exchanging data.  Is that right?

Comment: @nephtes It's exactly what I want. You put it in the right words actually. Is this possible? Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I haven't dealt with Apache httpd internals for a long time.  That being said... what you want is actually very similar to Apache's [WebSocket proxy module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html), so it should be possible.

Comment: In particular, a request handler can access the underlying socket with `ap_get_conn_socket(r->connection)`.  Getting the module to behave in a way that won't put the request in a nonsensical state will be trickier.  However, The source of mod_wstunnel is [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_wstunnel.c); that should help guide you.  Good luck!

Comment: @nepthes please, post the last comment as an answer (*or both combined*). And I will accept it. The `ap_get_conn_socket()` appears to be precisely what I need. I only have to deal with the apache not interfering with the request anymore.

Comment: Done.  Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is actually very similar to Apache's [WebSocket proxy module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html), so it should be possible.

In particular, a request handler can access the underlying socket with `ap_get_conn_socket(r->connection)`. Getting the module to behave in a way that won't put the request in a nonsensical state will be trickier. However, the source of *mod_wstunnel* is [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_wstunnel.c); that should help guide you. Good luck!

Comment: I can't believe how helpful your `ap_get_conn_socket()` suggestion was. After that just use `ap_send_interim_response()`, `ap_finalize_request_protocol()` and `ap_set_keepalive()` and I am doing exactly what I intended. Thanks.